# Bootstrap Collapse Show Method - Prevent from jumping to section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I prevent page from jumping to section with has hash id when manually triggering the `.collapse('show')` method?

For example when I have the following url

```
  http:example.com/page.php?#collapseOne
```

I use the following jquery which will expand the section with the hash id but it also jumps to that section.

```
        var anchor = window.location.hash;
        $(".collapse").collapse('hide');
        $(anchor).collapse('show'); 

        // this doesnt work becuase the .collapse('show') seems to overide it
        if (location.hash) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }, 1);
        }
```

How can i prevent it from jumping to that section when I manually call `.collapse('show') as in the example above - all I want to do is open it not jump to it?

Html code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" aria-multiselectable="true">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" id="headingOne">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
             Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="panel-body">
              Lorem ipsum
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" id="headingTwo">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              Collapsible Group Item #2
            </a>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
         <div class="panel-body">
             Lorem ipsum
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you copy+paste your html code as well with JS

Comment: @MeeneshJain see updated code.

Comment: It would be great if you could add a https://plnkr.co/

Comment: How about we replace actual id with a custom attribute and then we will be able to avoid the default browser behaviour. i.e. change `'id="headingOne"` to `data-section-id="headingOne"'`, and then use `var anchor = "[data-section-id='" + window.location.hash + "']";` for expanding